# Put response of REST-API in variable Windows Batch File

Tags: rest, curl, stripe-payments, windows-scripting

i am new to Windows Batch File Scripting. Could anyone explain me how i can extract one value of an REST API Response into a variable?

i made this call:

```
    curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers -u sk_live_1qwnCoXXXXXXXXXXXXX: -d card[number]=494XXXXXXX9 -d card[exp_month]=10 -d card[exp_year]=2022 -d card[cvc]=081 -d email=XXXXXXXXXXXX
{
  "id": "**cus_DqXXXXXXXXXXTu**",
  "object": "customer",
  "account_balance": 0,
  "created": 1540311116,
  "currency": null,
  "default_source": "card_1DOXXXXXXMf",
  "delinquent": false,
  "description": null,
  "discount": null,
  "email": "XXXXXXXXXX",
  "invoice_prefix": "69C53EF",
  "livemode": true,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "shipping": null,
  "sources": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "card_1DOXXXXXXXXXXf",
        "object": "card",
        "address_city": null,
        "address_country": null,
        "address_line1": null,
        "address_line1_check": null,
        "address_line2": null,
        "address_state": null,
        "address_zip": null,
        "address_zip_check": null,
        "brand": "Visa",
        "country": "DE",
        "customer": "**cus_DXXXXXXXTu**",
        "cvc_check": "pass",
        "dynamic_last4": null,
        "exp_month": 10,
        "exp_year": 2022,
        "fingerprint": "1WXXXXXXXXXX5",
        "funding": "prepaid",
        "last4": "XXXX",
        "metadata": {
        },
        "name": null,
        "tokenization_method": null
      }
    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 1,
    "url": "/v1/customers/cus_Dq8XXXXXXXTu/sources"
  },
  "subscriptions": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [

    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 0,
    "url": "/v1/customers/cus_Dq8XXXXXXXTu/subscriptions"
  },
  "tax_info": null,
  "tax_info_verification": null
}
```

I have to extract the id starting with "cus_" in first line of response and this id in sources section starting with "card_"

I have search through google, but maybe i didn't see the right answer.

Need this script to automate the invoicing in our inventory managment system.

Answer (score 0):

whilst not completely impossible, parsing json is *far* more advanced than what people *should* be doing with MS.bat scripting, which is a rather simple language. if you can, please switch to a better scripting language, this would be trivial in something like PHP or Python or Perl. for example with php-cli, which you can get [here](https://windows.php.net/download/), it'd be:

```
<?php
$json=trim(shell_exec('curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers -u sk_live_1qwnCoXXXXXXXXXXXXX: -d card[number]=494XXXXXXX9 -d card[exp_month]=10 -d card[exp_year]=2022 -d card[cvc]=081 -d email=XXXXXXXXXXXX'));
$data=json_decode($json,true);
$id=$data['id'];
$id2=$data['sources']['data'][0]['id'];
echo "first id: {$id} - data id: {$id2}";
```

and if you set up php-cli's php.exe as the default handler for .php files, you can run your php script directly from the command line, example:

[image]